# Amdahl's law -- how does the book get $8000/131.58% = $38.00?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

Did a simple Amdahl's law equation and received the same answer(s) as the book...

```
Fraction of work: 60% CPU, 40% disk.
SCPU = 1/((1-f)+(f/k)) = 1/((1-0.60)+(0.60/1.4)) = 120.69%
SDISK= 1/((1-f)+(f/k)) = 1/((1-0.40)+(0.40/2.5)) = 131.58%
```

...with the exception of the following answer.

```
$8000/131.58% = $38.00 for the disk upgrade
```

How did the book get this answer??  8000/131.58 is obviously not 38.  Original question posted below.

**Original question**

Suppose the daytime processing load consists of 60% CPU activity and 40% disk activity.
Your customers are complaining that the system is slow. After doing some research, you
have learned that you can upgrade your disks for $8,000 to make them 2.5 times as fast as
they are currently. You have also learned that you can upgrade your CPU to make it 1.4 as
fast for $5,000.

Which would you choose to yield the best performance improvement for the least
amount of money?

http://ubt.albabsd.org/Semestri3/SHK3/IM/IM-Ch7.PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book they used 5000$ as the cost for both cases. 5000/131.58 = 37.9996. 
It is a mistake.